# How does Geralt transport his swords?

Tags: the-witcher

A significant difference between *The Witcher* game and its Netflix interpretation was shown in the series teaser, where Geralt carries only one sword behind his back.

In the games Geralt is carrying permanently both of his swords.

How does he originally carry them in the books?

Comment: The series is not an interpretation of the game, it is an adaption of the books that the game is based on.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the books Geralt only carries one sword at once strapped to his back.

> As he took off his coat those around him noticed that he carried a sword— 
>   not something unusual in itself, nearly every man in Wyzim carried a weapon 
>   —but no one carried a sword strapped to his back as if it were a bow or a 
>   quiver.
>
> <sub>*The Last Wish*</sub>

He keeps his other sword, whichever he isn’t using at that time, strapped to his horse, Roach.

> Leaning over, the witcher pulled back the blanket which covered the 
>   horse’s side and uncovered another sword strapped to the saddlebag—one 
>   with a shining, ornate guard and black corrugated hilt.
>
> <sub>*The Last Wish*</sub>

Comment: I haven’t read all of the books but I believe this is the case throughout.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClWcN.png

Comment: @Valorum That looks like game artwork for the cover to me.

Comment: Well, for quite some time had only one sword, or even none.

Comment: worth to note that in the "Season of the storms" he lost both swords - this means that at least sometimes he carries them both.

Comment: Oh god is *that* how they translated the horse's name? I mean, it's technically correct, but reads so weirdly.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It's a weird name in original too :P And in czech, she's named "Klepna" (gossip) for some reason. The translations are just weird.

Comment: @Luaan The horse name is Płotka, however gossip in polish is "plotka" so possibly translation error.

Comment: In german it's "Plötze" which seems to be also some kind of fish

Comment: Geralt have one sword. People know that witchers have two of them "one for monster one for people" and they never know with one is the one strapped to his back.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Płotka (fish) is Roach (fish) in English. In kingdom Come: deliverance there is quest with Roach bought from "strange polish guy with white hair". Translator to POLISH translated this obvious reference as "Karaluch".

Comment: @Valorum The release of the Witcher games (especialy Witcher III) boosted the popularity of the franchise by several orders of magnitude, even though the books and the game have significant differences. It appears that in order to better cash in on that popularity, some of the book artworks were replaced to look more like the artwork of the games, even though it might conflict with the descriptions in the books. The Netflix adaption is explicitly based on the books and not on the games. So those who only know the franchise from the games might be in for a few surprises.

Answer (score 3):

My take is that this is a game thing. Basically, in the game you can expect to get jumped by monsters roaming the country-side at any time, out of the blue. So Geralt needs to have 2 swords at the ready.

In the books, if he senses something suspicious out in the country-side, he'll have far more time to prepare and will often know what he is facing in advance. Given his witcher senses, he almost always got the upper hand and isn't likely to get suddenly ambushed, like a careless player of the game could be.

In addition to what's mentioned in TheLethalCarrot's answer, there is also this:

(*The Last Wish*, Voice of Reason chapter 4)

Geralt speaking to the woman Iola:

> As you can see, I carry two. Every witcher does. It's said, spitefully, the silver one is for monsters and the iron for humans. But that's wrong. As there are monsters which can be struck down only with a silver blade, so there are those for whom iron is lethal. And, Iola, not just any iron, it must come from a meteorite.

The game fails to mention this completely and the game mechanics don't reflect this at all either.

Comment: In the "Season of storms" Geralt admits that the "must be made from a meteorite" is bullshit  - there is nothing particularly special about his steel sword (only the great quality). Also, sometimes humans are monsters...

Comment: @Yasskier Who should we believe then, Geralt or Geralt? :) In this chapter quoted he's making various confessions and has no reason to boast or lie.

Comment: in your quote, he is speaking to a barely-known girl that he is in bed with. In the "Season of storms", he is speaking to Dandelion, his long-time friend. He also describes why there is a myth about the need for a meteorite iron  - metaphysical mumbo-jumbo about meteorite falling through different elemental plane and admitting that this is a lie and witchers are happy to use regular (although well-made) steel swords.